# SQL Kihlman whats wrong with the syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Find all companies and the each salary they Have paid. the list should only include company names, year and salary!

The table looks like this: tblCompany, ComRegNo, ComName(company name) and the other table tblAnnualPay, AnnPay, AnnYear, ComRegNo, WorRegNo.

My code is

```
SELECT ComName,AnnYear, AnnPay FROM tblCompany, tblAnnualPay
```

It says Conditions are wrong: Conditions are expected but all are lacking. 
What is wrong ?

I'm supposed to select ComName from tblCompany, and AnnPay,AnnYear from tblAnnualPay.

Comment: A classic "How to ask a bad question" example.

Comment: Posting any sort of code (including SQL) as an image is a non-starter here. It's difficult to read, it's impossible to copy/paste for testing, it's inaccessible to those with visual impairments, it's impossible for those using mobile devices to view (and costs them data), and images are frequently blocked by corporate proxies. It's 10 times more complicated to do a screen capture, save it to a file, and upload it to an image than it is to simply copy/paste code here. We also need you to provide an actual textual description of the problem that is meaningful, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Find all companies and the each salary they Have paid. the list should only include company names, year and salary!

The table looks like this: tblCompany, ComRegNo, ComName(company name) and the other table tblAnnualPay, AnnPay, AnnYear, ComRegNo, WorRegNo. 

My code is = SELECT ComName,AnnYear, AnnPay FROM tblCompany, tblAnnualPay. It says Conditions are wrong: Conditions are expected but all are lacking. What is wrong ?

Comment: *Why doesn't this work?* is not a **specific question**, and you've provided no information in your post that is meaningful or describes a problem. *It doesn't work** is not a useful problem description unless you explain exactly what *does not work* means. We're not mind readers. If it's not worth your effort to write a complete, specific question, why should it be worth ours answering it? I'd strongly suggest that you visit [How do I ask a good question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: You need to JOIN the tables, and the missing JOIN is what's causing the *Conditions are expected but all are lacking* error. It appears the tables JOIN on `ComRegNo`

Comment: SELECT ComName,AnnYear, AnnPay FROM tblCompany, tblAnnualPay WHERE tblCompany.ComRegNo=tblAnnualPay.ComRegNo . This code worked :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ComName,AnnYear, AnnPay FROM tblCompany, tblAnnualPay WHERE tblCompany.ComRegNo=tblAnnualPay.ComRegNo  This code worked (Y)